# Backbonejs with Mongolab

Tags: javascript, mongodb, backbone.js, mlab

I'm working on a few backbone apps that require ruby on the backend to connect to the database and that is about it. I'm trying to rule out ruby for my demos (I'm aware this is a security risk for production)

I noticed on AngularJS site they had and example ( http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/ ) where it it connected directly to the mongolabs service without a backend lang.

```
// This is a module for cloud persistance in mongolab - https://mongolab.com
angular.module('mongolab', ['ngResource']).
    factory('Project', function($resource) {
      var Project = $resource('https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases' +
          '/angularjs/collections/projects/:id',
          { apiKey: '4f847ad3e4b08a2eed5f3b54' }, {
            update: { method: 'PUT' }
      }
  );

  Project.prototype.update = function(cb) {
    return Project.update({id: this._id.$oid},
        angular.extend({}, this, {_id:undefined}), cb);
  };

  Project.prototype.destroy = function(cb) {
    return Project.remove({id: this._id.$oid}, cb);
  };

  return Project;
});
```

Is this possible in backbone? If so how can I go about doing it? I tried to look at how AngularJS did it to emulate it but I'm pretty new to backbone and not quite understanding how they're doing so.

Answer (score 2):

The AngularJS example is a wrapper for Mongolab to save you writing all the boilerplate code yourself. At the end of the day all you need to do to access the service directly is call it from ajax:

```
$.ajax( { url: "https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/
                     your_db/collections/your_collection?apiKey=your_key",
      data: JSON.stringify( { "your_field" : "your_data" } ),
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json" } );
```

**Edit:**

[MongoLab Now Supports Two-Factor Authentication](http://blog.mongolab.com/tag/security/)